# llenar tabla html con json

Tags: html, ajax, json

Hola tengo un problema al llenar una tabla  me sale undefined al querer mostrar los datos el que arroja el json en la tabla...

El json que tengo es el siguiente

```
{
"calificaciones": {
"1": {
"nombre_materia": "Matematicas ",
"semestre": "1",
"par1": "9",
"par2": "7",
"par3": "8",
"calif_final": "6"
},
"2": {
"nombre_materia": "INFORMÁTICA I",
"semestre": "1",
"par1": "9",
"par2": "8",
"par3": "5",
"calif_final": "6"
 }
},
"promedio_final": "6.20",
"promedio_p1": 12,
"promedio_p2": 11.8,
"promedio_p3": 8.8
}
```

La tabla html que tengo es la siguiente  la cual lleno con el json y en la cual el body sale undefined

```
<table id="table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Materia</th>
                    <th>Semestre</th>
                    <th>Parcial 1</th>
                    <th>Parcial 2</th>
                    <th>Parcial 3</th>
                    <th>Calificacion Final</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyProducto">

            </tbody>
```

El ajax que utilizo para llenar el body de la tabla es el siguiente creo que es el equivocado pero no se en que parte me e equivocado ya que en la consola me arroja el json donde si lo va a traer a la url

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'calificaciones.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {matricula: '112020',ciclo:'2018-2019'},
    success: function(response) {
        var valor = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.nombre_materia + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.semestre + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.parcial1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.parcial2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.parcial3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.calificaciones.calif_final + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("#tbodyProducto").html(valor);
    }
});
```

Comment: Necesitas parsear tu response con JSON.parse(), para convertir tu JSON en un objeto y poder utilizarlo.

Comment: si coloco json.parse(response);  me marca el siguiente error VM843:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: tiene que ser con mayusculas la palabra JSON, así JSON.parse(response)

Comment: Revisa bien el archivo `calificaciones.php` pues en él **no debe haber ninguna salida por pantalla que no sea el JSON**. Ese error hace pensar que estás imprimiendo otras cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como por lo visto tu clave es un `string` "0", "1", "2"; con un `foreach` puede recorrerlo, y como veo que quieres pintar una tabla te recomiendo `appendTo`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'calificaciones.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {matricula: '112020',ciclo:'2018-2019'},
    success: function(response) {
        $("#tbodyProducto").html('');
        $.each(response.calificaciones, function(index, item){
           var valor = 
            '<tr>' +
              '<td>' + item.nombre_materia + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + item.semestre + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + item.parcial1 + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + item.parcial2 + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + item.parcial3 + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + item.calif_final + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
            $(valor).appendTo("#tbodyProducto");
        });
        
        $("#tbodyCalificaciones").html('');
         var valor = 
          '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + response.promedio_final + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response.promedio_p1 + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response.promedio_p2 + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response.promedio_p3 + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
        $(valor).appendTo("#tbodyCalificaciones");
    }
});
```

Comment: siegue apareciendo undefined @gabriel jeremy

Comment: era response.calificaciones ya corregui la respuesta. te deberia funcionar

Comment: si ya me funciono una duda mas al querer imrimir "promedio_final": "6.20",
    "promedio_p1": 12,
    "promedio_p2": 11.8,
    "promedio_p3": 8.8  en otra tabla me lo imprime dos veces sabes por que razon?

Comment: porque esos son atributos del objeto y tienes que hacerlos por separado, edito la respuesta

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver eres un crack, gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Parese que intentas imprimir las cualificaciones directamente `response.calificaciones.nombre_materia`
Y el archivo json que muestras seria response.calificaciones.1.nombre_materia
fijate en la estructura del json

```
{
    "calificaciones": {
        "1": {
            "nombre_materia": "Matematicas ",
            "semestre": "1",
            "par1": "9",
            "par2": "7",
            "par3": "8",
            "calif_final": "6"
        },
        "2": {
            "nombre_materia": "INFORMÁTICA I",
            "semestre": "1",
            "par1": "9",
            "par2": "8",
            "par3": "5",
            "calif_final": "6"
        }
    },
    "promedio_final": "6.20",
    "promedio_p1": 12,
    "promedio_p2": 11.8,
    "promedio_p3": 8.8
}
```

Puedes hacer un loop para imprimir las calificaciones con

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.calificaciones.length; i++) {
  console.log(response.calificaciones[i].nombre_materia)
}
```

Comment: Puede que response.calificaciones[i].nombre_materia no funcione ya que en el json el 1 y 2 son cadenas de caracteres (String) y el valor de i es un entero (Integer)